# backgroundView/backgroundColor on UITableView in iOS5.1

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios5

I'm trying to change the background of my table to an image, this works fine in 4.3:

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundTile.png"]];
```

However in 5.1 it doesn't, all I get is a white background. I have tried these alternatives, none of them work.

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundTile.png"]];
table.backgroundView = view;
```

or this

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *bgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundTile.png"]]; 
table.backgroundView = bgview;
[bgview release];
```

or this

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *bgview = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(table.frame.origin.x, table.frame.origin.y, table.frame.size.width, table.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundTile.png"]];
table.backgroundView = bgview;
```

Curiously, if instead of using colorWithPatternImage, I use say greenColor, then that works. I'm trying to get an image though.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the missing transparency on the png.